# Which host of redis in config, if running in the same k8 cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab, redis

I am running a redis cluster `helm install -n redis staging bitnami/redis-cluster` in my k8s cluster and want to use this with a self hosted gitlab. In the [docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/charts/advanced/external-redis/index.html#configure-the-chart) I see I have to set

```
redis:
  install: false
global:
  redis:
    host: ???
    password: enabled
    key: secret
    secret: staging-redis-secret
```

My question is which host do I have to set, because everything is running in the same k8s cluster. Do I have to set the local IP like `10.42.0.4`. And if yes, the IP of which redis container as I am running 6 of them.

With that config I can run

```
helm install \
    gitlab gitlab/gitlab \
    --namespace gitlab \
    --version 5.2.3 \
    -f config.yaml
```

The secret is set by

```
kubectl create secret generic staging-redis-secret --from-literal=secret=$(kubectl get secret --namespace "redis" staging-redis-cluster -o jsonpath="{.data.redis-password}")
```

Answer (score 0):

Kubernetes runs an internal DNS server called CoreDNS. This should take care of all kind of internal name resolution between pods/services. You should never really hardcode any static IP into a configuration file, as this IP might no longer exists next time you reboot the whole cluster.

Start using domain names for everything and stick to that.